# Updating an existing Memcached record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I have an application that needs to perform multiple network queries each one of those returns 100 records.

I'd like to keep all the results (several thousand or so) together in a single Memcached record named according to the user's request.

Is there a way to append data to a Memcached record or do I need to read and write it back and forth and combine the old results with the new ones by the means of my application?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm using Rails 3.2

Comment: You might want to consider redis. Personally I haven't used it but I guess it allows such operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to append anything to a memcached key. You'd have to read it in and out of storage every time.

redis does allow this sort of operation, however, as rubish points out -- it has a native list type that allows you to push new data onto it. Check out the [redis list documenation](http://redis.io/commands#list) for information on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks! But will it be right to use Redis for the data that doesn't need to be persistent? I use key:value store only for caching.

Comment: Redis data doesn't need to persist to disk at all. Check out the [redis persistence documentation](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) for more information, but if you absolutely don't want anything saving to disk, you can elect to save nothing to disk and keep the entire datastore in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class that'll emulate list in memcached (which is actually what i did)... appending to record isn't atomic operation, so it'll generate errors that'll accumulate over time (at least in memcached). Beside it'll be very slow.

As pointed out Redis has native lists, but it can be emulated in any noSQL / K-V storage solution.